# proper way to check if input "promo code" matches with a database column

Tags: php, html, sql

I would like to ask, what will be the best way to code using SQL and PHP, on how to check if the input in a textfield matches with a value in an SQL column?

[image: table]

I only have three values in the table. my targets are:

- retrieve (POST) the value of the input
- check the whole column to see if any matches the "promo code" typed
- the "tinyint" used value will turn to 1
- echo or affect other database tables if conditions are met

pseudocode will be alright, I would just like the proper procedure.

UPDATE: I tried the solution from @Bitwise Creative, im not getting an echo to appear, which part did i do wrong? also, i got my db where the table is located using a variable.

```
      <form method="get">
        <input type="text" name="lux_code" placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE" style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" class="full_width btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
      </form>

      <?php

      $routePath = "../";

      require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
        $dbConfig = new config_db();
        $db = $dbConfig->init();

        if (isset($_POST['redeem']) && $_POST['redeem'] == 'REDEEM'){
          if (isset($_POST['lux_code']) && $_POST['lux_code']) {
            // Short-cutting the DB code for demonstration...
            $rows = $db->query('SELECT * FROM promocode_3 WHERE coupon_code = ? AND used = ?', array($_POST['lux_code'], 0));
            if (!$rows) {
                // Code not found (however you want to handle that...)
                echo 'Code not found.';
            } else {
                // Code found and marked as used in DB
                $db->query('UPDATE promocode_3 SET used = ? WHERE coupon_code = ?', array(1, $_POST['lux_code']));
                // Additional handling...
                echo 'Code accepted!';
            }
          }
        }
       ?>
```

Comment: This part `// Short-cutting the DB code for demonstration...` means that I don't know how your DB connector works, so using a common demo. Your actual DB code will likely need to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `coupon_code` has a unique index... Something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['code']) && $_POST['code']) {
    // Short-cutting the DB code for demonstration...
    $rows = $db->query('SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE coupon_code = ? AND used = ?', array($_POST['code'], 0));
    if (!$rows) {
        // Code not found (however you want to handle that...)
        echo 'Code not found.';
    } else {
        // Code found and marked as used in DB
        $db->query('UPDATE coupons SET used = ? WHERE coupon_code = ?', array(1, $_POST['code']));
        // Additional handling...
        echo 'Code accepted!';
    }
}
```

Comment: tried doing you solution, i think its just something a little wrong with my procedure, i updated it in my question.

Comment: everything seems to be connected

Comment: I don't know how your DB connector executes queries. You'll need to adapt my queries to your DB connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
$couponcode = $_POST['coupon'];
$sql = "update table_name set used = 1 where coupon_code = $couponcode && used = 0";
```

Comment: im not trying to update, just compare, assuming there are already "coupon_codes: and an input from a textfield matches on on the column

Comment: so you just want to check that if input coupon code is used or not right..?

Comment: If you are not using UPDATE statement, how can you change the `used` value to 1?

Comment: oh i misunderstood the update, yes its after comparin, my bad

Comment: @Akshaykatale Your query is problematic, and will probably lead to SQL Injection.

Comment: If after running the update, you can check the number of rows affected, this will be 1 if a row was found and updated, 0 means an unused coupon doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to retrieve all your `unused` coupon codes and then iterate over the collection and check if the posted `value` is a match.

I would write a function in my `functions.php` file as so:

```
function getCoupons() {
    global $db;
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE `used` = 0");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchall();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I would then call the function and store the results into an array in my `test.php` file like so:

```
$coupons = getCoupons();
```

I would also need the `posted` value, I'll retrieve it like so:

```
$couponCode = $_POST['coupon'];
```

I would then iterate over the result set to check for a match in the same file:

```
$match = false;
foreach($coupons as $coupon){

    if($coupon['coupon_code'] == $couponCode){ //check to see if posted value matches

        $match = true;

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE coupons SET used = 
        '1' WHERE p3id = :id");
        $stmt2->execute(array(
            ':id'=>$coupon['id'] 
        ));

        break;

    }

}

if($match){

    echo 'Coupon code exists!';

} else {

    echo 'No Coupon code exists!';

}
```

Comment: This is not the "best way". What if he has 500k coupon codes? Pull down the entire table and loop through each row? Not to mention, you're not even pulling just the unused ones, your query pulls ALL rows... Also, did you ever plan to break out of the loop? XD

Comment: I have updated my answer. I was a bit hasty when I wrote the above. Thank you for letting me know. :)